# Grab inner text from HTML that isn't from a header

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

Using HTMLAgilityPack for C#, how would I go about grabbing the inner text from the HTML that isn't from a `<h1-6>`. I don't want to use Regular Expressions, but HTMLAgilityPack.

My current approach:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml (text);
text = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode ("//body").InnerText;
```

This has issues and doesn't quite work when dealing with a large range of text. It would be better to remove the header tags and then grab the inner text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove unwanted tags, then get body.innerText:

```
string[] tagsToRemove = { "h1", "h2", "h3", h4", "h5", "h6" };
List<string> tagsToRemoveList = tagsToRemove.ToList();
doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
    .Where(n => tagsToRemoveList.Contains(n..Name.ToLowerCase()))
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(n => n.Remove());
```

Comment: This is a great, simple approach to this. Appreciate it!